# regex search and replace

Tags: html, regex, replace, dreamweaver

I need to do a massive search and replace in Dreamweaver. Currently, I have this HTML:

```
data-number="10" data-type="normal"
```

and I need to get this data in to an id:

```
id="normal-10"
```

Is there any way to do this using a regular expression search and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
data-number="([^"]+)" data-type="([^"]+)"
```

with this:

```
id="$2-$1"
```

Each group matches the part between quotes, and `$n` refers to that group number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
data-number="(\d*)" data-type="normal"
```

And for the replace field:

```
id="normal-$1"
```